# Easy way to create an object from base class

Tags: java, object, constructor, this

Let assume we have :

```
class A {
}
```

and also

```
class B extends A {

  B(A object) {
    this = object; //this is not possible.
  }
}
```

As we know, we cannot set any value to keywords in Java (this). Is there any too easy way to create B object that has the same fields value with A object ?

Comment: Do you mean how to create a copy constructor the easiest way?

Comment: yeap. is this too absurd question ? i got negative points

Comment: I don't think it's absurd but looks like you haven't even tried. I would simply create the copy constructor in the base class and in subclasses call `super(a);`. Now if you naively ask *should I generate the copy of several fields manually?* the answer would be: make sure it's done, via manually or code generation tool, but the code must be there.

Comment: i tried and searched a lot. However i didnt find anythings and i asked. then i got negative points :) i guess it can be because this provides us so easy syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to copy all the fields, one by one.  There is no easier way.  You could write a tool to generate this code for you.  In general, this is avoided in Java (possibly because it's painful and error prone) and delegation is often used, if there is not a simpler solution to your problem. i.e. there is usually an alternative.

Comment: hmm i got it. By the way, does Java have : new A() { this.f = f, ... } syntax like C# does ?

Comment: @user14570 that seriosly demonstrates that you have to learn the basics of Java. Don't try to rush to accomplish something if you won't dedicate the time to learn the basics.

Answer (score 1):

That cannot work as the variable this is a final one. So you could do something like this:

```
public class A {

       private String hello;
       private String something;

       public A(String hello, String something){
          this.hello = hello;
          this.something = something;
       }

       public String getHello() {
          return hello;
       }

       public void setHello(String hello) {
          this.hello = hello;
        }

        public String getSomething() {
           return something;
        } 

        public void setSomething(String something) {
          this.something = something;
        }

}
```

You can then use class A in B as below:

```
  public class B extends A{

      public B(A object) {
         super(object.getHello(),object.getSomething());
      }

  }
```